# Label giving the MAX result in an Index-Match lookup

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I'm doing a table with the best outputs of an experiment. In this table I need to display the best (maximum) result for every combination of Sample and Method. And also the Test that gave this best result.

After checking similar questions here, I got how to do the first part (MAX result), but got no solution for the second part (label/test giving that result).

Here's a simplified table to see if you can help me to understand how to do that:

Data Table

```
       A     B          C        D       E
1                      Test1    Test2   Test3
2   Sample1 Method1     1.6     2.2     0.1
3   Sample2 Method1     1.5     1.3     0.6
4   Sample3 Method1     1       0       0.6
5   Sample1 Method2     0.5     0.1     1.7
6   Sample2 Method2     1.5     0.5     1
7   Sample3 Method2     0.4     0.5     2.7
8   Sample1 Method3     0.7     1.7     1
9   Sample2 Method3     1.1     1.1     1.2
10  Sample3 Method3     0.6     0.4     1.5
```

And here Is a draft of the table I hope to build

```
   G        H       I       J       K       L       M
1 BEST      Sample1 Sample1 Sample2 Sample2 Sample3 Sample3
2 RESULTS   ValMax  Test    ValMax  Test    ValMax  Test
3 Method1   2.2             1.5             1   
4 Method2   1.7             1.5             2.7 
5 Method3   1.7             1.2             1.5
```

As you can see I already get how to check which was the maximum value of each combination, thanks to this array function (at H3):

```
=MAX(IF(($A$2:$A$10=H1)*($B$2:$B$10=G3);$C$2:$E$10))
```

(and  <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>  + <kbd>Enter</kbd> )

But for the second part I have no clue. I need to extract, from the "row 1", which of the 3 Tests (Test1, Test2 and Test3 at Columns C, D and E) contains the MAX value for the Row that contains the right combination of Sample and Method.
I tried with something like this (at I3):

```
=INDEX($A$1:$E$10; 1; MATCH(H3&H$1&G3; $C$2:$E$10&$A$2:$A$10&$B$2:$B$10;0))
```

(and  <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>  + <kbd>Enter</kbd> )

But is obviously not working, because I'm mixing rows and columns.
How do I get the value from row 1 (Test) that corresponds with the Maximum value of the combination of Method and Sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'd probably use VBA to construct the table, the following formula will return the Test that corresponds to the sample:

```
I3:  =INDEX($C$1:$E$1,1,MATCH(H3,INDEX($C$2:$E$10,MATCH(TRUE,IF((I$1=$A$2:$A$10)*($G3=$B$2:$B$10),TRUE),0),0),0))
```

You will need to adjust addresses for the different columns, or combine this with your other formula in an `IF` function to decide whether to display the score or the test name.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Ron. Now it seems evident, but I wasn't able to get there by myself. I applied it to all the dataset, no need for re-adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non CSE Array formula that will do it:

```
=INDEX($C$1:$E$1,MAX(INDEX(($G3=$B$2:$B$10)*($A$2:$A$10=I$1)*($C$2:$E$10=H3)*(COLUMN($C$2:$E$10)-COLUMN($C$2:$C$2)+1),)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott. This also works perfectly. I don't usually use this king of functions: (Column()-COLUMN()+1)
I think I need to dig a little bit more in this function to start using these arguments.